# Undefined result on ajax request ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

**This is my Context Class**

```
public class UserInfoContext
{
    private readonly MVCDbContext _db;

    public UserInfoContext(MVCDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<List<UserInformation>> GetAll()
    {
        var list = await _db.UserInfo.ToListAsync();
        return list;
    }
```

**This is my Controller**

```
private UserInfoContext _ui_context;        
    public UserInformationController(UserInfoContext ui_context)
    {
        _ui_context = ui_context;
    }

    // GET: UserInformation
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoadUserList()
    {
        var list = await _ui_context.GetAll();
        return new JsonResult(list);
    }
```

**And this is my AJAX request**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    loadUser();
    function loadUser() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/UserInformation/LoadUserList",  
            data: {},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {       
                var html = '';
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Id + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.FirstName + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.LastName + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Location + '</td>';                      
                    html += '</tr>';
                });
                $('#table_user').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**This is the result im getting**

I'm getting "undefined result".

[image: im getting undefined result]

**This is the log on debugger network tab**

[image: my log on debugger]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're accessing variables with the first letter uppercase in your ajax request, while in your json are written in lower case. Could it be the problem?

Comment: @ALFA should i change "item.Id" to "item.id"?

Comment: @PaulVincentDoroyan check my answer please

Comment: haven't try @FatikhanGasimov

Comment: Yes try to use lowercase

Comment: Thank you @ALFA but I wonder why it doesnt work when the first letter is Uppercase?

Comment: Simply because you defined your JSON with lowercases and `variable access` is case-sensitive. So `Id` is not the same as `id`. If your json would have had `Id` with uppercase, you would have accessed it using `item.Id`, this is not the case.

Comment: oh okay thank you very much @ALFA

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your first letter is uppercase (eg: Firstname). But you have to start with lowercase (`item.id`, `item.firstName` etc.)

```
 $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.id + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.firstName + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.lastName + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.location + '</td>';                      
                    html += '</tr>';
                });
```

Comment: Thank you @Fatikhan Gasimov but I wonder why it doesnt work when the first letter is Uppercase? just figuring out